# How can I autoscale my Azure Kubernetes nodepool before resources run out

Tags: azure, kubernetes, autoscaling, aks

I did some testing today with my autoscaling setup on Azure Kubernetes. I noticed that when an autoscale was triggered, it took a while for the next node to spin up, so the last pod had to wait a long time to be scheduled. I would like to make it so that when my server reaches a certain threshold, new nodes are added, but pods can still be scheduled on the already-running nodes. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer the question of how to trigger autoscaling such that a pod does not have to wait for a new node, [this article](https://medium.com/scout24-engineering/cluster-overprovisiong-in-kubernetes-79433cb3ed0e) describes an elegant strategy called "Pause Pods":

> [Pod Priority and Preemption](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/pod-priority-preemption) are Kubernetes features that allow you to
> assign priorities to pods. In a nutshell this means that when the
> cluster is low on resources it can preempt (remove) lower-priority
> pods in order to make space for higher-priority pods waiting to be
> scheduled. With pod priority we can run some dummy pods solely for
> reserving extra space in the cluster which will be freed as soon as
> “real” pods need to run. The pods used for the reservation should
> ideally not be using any resources but just sit there and do nothing.
> You might have heard of pause containers which are already used in
> Kubernetes for a [different purpose](https://www.ianlewis.org/en/almighty-pause-container). One property of the pause
> container is that it is mostly just calling the [pause](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/pause.2.html) syscall which
> means “sleep until a signal is received”.
>
> [image: Regular pods alongside overprovisioning pods]
>
> To sum it up, we can run
> a bunch of pause pods in our cluster with the sole purpose of
> reserving space to trick the cluster-autoscaler into adding extra
> nodes prematurely. Since these pods have a lower priority than regular
> pods they will be evicted from the cluster as soon as resources become
> scarce. The pause pods will then go into pending state which in turn
> triggers the cluster-autoscaler to add capacity. Overall, this is a
> quite elegant way to always have a dynamic buffer in the cluster.